# Загрузка файла JS

Tags: javascript, php

суть заключается в следующем:
в js происходит получение скрипта .php через XMLHttpRequest
js код:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.open('POST', 'file.php')
xhr.send()
```

php код:

```
readfile(path)
```

(Код приведен условно, а причина использования подобного кода - полное закрытие доступа к файлу иными способами извне, кроме как через скрипт). Изменять принцип уже поздно, поэтому надо довести до конца. Суть вопроса в том, как можно инициализировать загрузку файла полученного через xhr? То есть я могу записать ответ в `xhr.response`, но как начать загрузку методами js?

Comment: Не совсем понятно что значит "инициализировать загрузку файла полученного через xhr". Текст получен. Что еще с ним собираешься делать? Так же не понятно что значит "начать загрузку методами js"? Данные уже получены. Хотя в твоем "скрипте" нет собственно обработки ответа от сервера...

Comment: Я имею в виду как скачать файл, полученный таким скриптом. Именно на устройство клиента

Comment: Давай уточним. Ты таким образом хочешь получить некий файл с сервера в браузер на клиенте? Вот примеры такого действа. https://habr.com/ru/post/120917/   Допустим ты данные получил... Что будешь потом с ними делать? Т.к. сохранить их на диск клиента это еще одна задача.